# drupal 6 mini pager theming

Tags: php, drupal-6, overriding, block, pager

I am trying to theme particular pagers on the site and no matter what id I try it doesn't seem to get picked up. This is what I am using to theme all pagers now.

```
function Subtle_Hightlights_views_mini_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
  $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // max is the maximum page number
  $pager_max = $quantity;
  // End of marker calculations.


  $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
  if (empty($li_previous)) {
    $li_previous = "";
  }

  $li_next = theme('pager_next', (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
  if (empty($li_next)) {
    $li_next = "";
  }

  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {
    $items[] = array(
      'class' => 'pager-previous-mini',
      'data' => $li_previous,
    );
 if ($pager_current == 9){
    $li_next = "";
 }
    $items[] = array(
      'class' => 'pager-current-mini',
      'data' => t('@current of @max', array('@current' => $pager_current, '@max' => $pager_max)),
    );

    $items[] = array(
      'class' => 'pager-next-mini',
      'data' => $li_next,
    );
    return theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ul', array('class' => 'pager'));
  }
}
```

now this works to theme all mini pagers but when I try to apply the name of the view and block like this.

``` function Subtle_Hightlights_views_mini_pager__news_items__block_2($tags = array(), $limit = ``10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9) { ```

does nothing acts as though the code isnt there anymore. Anyone else tried this and it actually worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good step by step instructions on how you can overwrite the pager (mini or full). The only step that I would suggest that you do different is when you get to *list of theme function names that you can use to override your views pager inside your `template.php` file*, just use this module: [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). Once it's enabled it will provide in a much easier way the suggestions. If that fails, then just try the article's methods.

[Drupal 6 Override views pager theme function](http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-6-override-views-pager-theme-function)

Comment: thanks i will try the theme module and see if it gives me any other function names than i have previously tried but i have already tried the other option. It seems that i can not override individual pagers with my installation.

Comment: What theme are you using? Is it a sub-theme of another theme, for example Zen? And I think you can overwrite a pager, it's not installation related. You can do it per view, I'm just not sure if you can do it per display as well. Or that's not necessary?

Comment: its actually not a sub theme its a completely custom built theme. I know i should be able to override the pager per view, which is what i was trying, but the supported information i was given for this does not seem to work to do exactly that.

Comment: Well according to that document it should be something like this: `MYTHEME_views_mini_pager__MYVIEW`. So if your theme name is `Subtle_Hightlights` and the view name is `news_items`, then the overwriting function is `Subtle_Hightlights_views_mini_pager__news_items` (without `_block_2`). And make sure you clear the cache.